# Turtle name not defined

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and I'm a little confused, how come this works:

```
from turtle import 

def square(turtle):    
    tut.forward(100)   
    tut.right(90)        


space = Screen()         
tut = Turtle()        
square(tut)
```

but if I were to put the bottom section in another function like this:

```
from turtle import *

def square(turtle):    
    tut.forward(100)   
    tut.right(90)        


def big():
    space = Screen()         
    tut = Turtle()        
    square(tut) 

big()
```

it doesn't work because tut is not defined in the square function. If i change the name from tut to turtle, then it draws normally. How do I fix this if I want to draw using a name that I assigned to the turtle?

Answer (score 1):

When you define your `square` function you say what parameters it takes and what those parameters will be called inside the function.  The line:

```
def square(turtle):
```

says that the function takes one parameter, which inside the body of the function will be called "turtle".  If you want it to be called "tut" instead, change the name in the parameter list:

```
def square(tut):
    tut.forward(100)   
    tut.right(90)
```

The name that this value has in the *calling* function (`big`) doesn't matter.  You could call it `tut`, or `turtle`, or `donatello`, and within the body of `square` it will still be called whatever you named the parameter when you defined `square`.

```
def big():
    space = Screen()         
    leonardo = Turtle()
    raphael = Turtle()
    square(leonardo)  # inside "square" leonardo's called "tut"
    square(raphael)   # same for raphael
    square(Turtle())  # same for this nameless turtle!
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```py
from turtle import *

def square(tut):
    tut.forward(100)   
    tut.right(90)  

def big():
    tut = Turtle()
    space = Screen()
    square(tut)
```

Comment: This is just a repetition of an earlier answer.